# Sort a list of lists within a class Python

Tags: list, class, python-3.x

I have created the following

```
class uniquePlayers():

    def __init__(self):
        self._item = [ [] for i in range(5) ]
        self.count = 0

    def addPlayer(self, firstInstance, firstName, lastName, Country, long):
        self._item[0].append(firstInstance)
        self._item[1].append(firstName.lower())
        self._item[2].append(lastName.lower())
        self._item[3].append(Country)
        self._item[4].append(long.lower())
        self.count += 1

    def sortByKey(self, index = 4 ):
        self._item[index].sort()
```

I am trying to sort the whole class, keeping everything from the other lists following along. Obviously what I have done is just sort the 'long' list

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the data that belongs together together. So instead of having 5 lists with one attribute each, have a single list with all the player data:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._players = []

def addPlayer(self, firstInstance, firstName, lastName, Country, long):
    player = (firstInstance, firstName.lower(), lastName.lower(), Country, long.lower())
    self._players.append(player)

def sortByKey(self, index=4):
    self._players.sort(key=lambda x: x[index])
```

You could also use a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for the player data, to access it more easily, or even better, introduce a new type (class) for the players.